# Is there a way to add more than 2 series to a chart using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

So my issue is that I have 3 series to plot on the same graph using xlsxwriter, however when I use the combine function listed here (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_chart_combined.html) the second combine over-writes the first. If I try to combine both using the code chart.combine(chart1, chart2) it gives an error. Is there a way to have three series on the same graph using xlsxwriter?

Comment: Does you need to add 3 series to one chart type or to combine 3 different chart types. The first option is possible but the second currently possible.

Comment: I was trying to combine two different chart types into 1, one had two line series and the other had one column series, turns out I had already used the column chart in another chart so I needed to recreate it and then combine, worked perfectly after that!

Answer (score -1):

I've done this with two different chart types:
Say I have a column chart and I want to add a line chart also:

```
column_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
column_chart.add_series({
    'name': f"={variable}!A4",
    'categories': f"={variable}!B3:M3",
    'values': f"={variable}!B4:M4",
    'y_axis': True,
    })
line_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
line_chart.add_series({
    'name': f"={variable}!A5",
    'categories': f"={variable}!B3:M3",
    'values': f"={variable}!B5:M5",
    'y2_axis': True,
    })
column_chart.combine(line_chart)
```